# Vue.js on safari 5.0.6

Tags: vue.js

I've updated my Webpage with some new features using Vue.js.
The problem comes when some computers in my office doesn't work as expected, as far as I'm concerned Safari is compatible with ecmascript 5  and that should be enough to run the page as it's supposed. 
Unfortunately it doesn't. Properties are set up as it should, v-show works fine, even transitions. But properties aren't being rendered on the page... To clarify, I'm talking about the ones that should be replaced in the Vue templates:

```
<box_example>
<span> {{ a_property }}</span>
</box_example>
```

a_property is never shown while in other browsers works as expected. Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Which is the dependency that makes it fail? Maybe I could shim it or at least detect that functionality lack and then redirect to an older javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, issues solved also in Safari 5.0.6 using `v-text` or `v-html` in the elements instead of the special quotation {{ }} or {{{ }}}.

Seem like using v-text/v-html allows a wider range of browsers. Could be useful to someone :-)